# Open shortcuts in batch files with spaces

Tags: batch-file, shortcut

I am trying to open a short cut on a desktop that has spaces in it?

every time I put the space in the batch file it doesn't recognize it.

sorry I am pretty new to all of this so...

```
@echo off
start BLS UK.lnk
pause
```

Shortcut location is: C:\Users\Jonathan.Gorbutt\Desktop

if needed

Really do appreciate all the help

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Users\Jonathan.Gorbutt\Desktop\BLS_UK.lnk"
pause
```

Note that the first quoted item in a `start` command is taken to be the window title.

---

This worked on my machine:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
start "" "C:\106x\with spaces\nasm manual.lnk"

GOTO :EOF
```

Where `nasm manual.lnk` had been copied from my desktop to `C:\106x\with spaces\`

Sadly `No luck anything else?` doesn't provide us with much of a clue about what happened. It all becomes a guessing game...

You are aware that the command (copied from your question) doesn't contain a space? `Jonathan.Gorbutt` is not the same as `Jonathan Gorbutt`

Comment: No luck anything else?

Comment: But there was a space in `BLS UK` where you have an underscore.  Changing the underscore back to a space should work.

Comment: @TripeHound : OP edited the underscore to a space after I'd formatted the code.

Comment: Ah, OK.  OP: this should work so long as it matches what you've actually got.

Comment: I know putting an empty title tag in a start command is to prevent errors, yet i've never run into any of those before i knew about it. It's just something i do without knowing why.

Answer (score 0):

Place double quotes around the shortcut like "C:\Users\Jonathan.Gorbutt\Desktop"

Comment: `code`
@echo off
echo "Opening 5 IFMS Sessoins
start "C:\Users\Jonathan.Gorbutt\Desktop BLS UK.ink"
pause
`code`
Just tried it just opens a command promt

Comment: That won't work..cant put double quotes inside double quotes.Wait are you trying to open an application shortcut from within a batch file? Why not run the exe instead?

Comment: The program I am opening doesn't seem to like it just gives out a load of errors and boots me off.